# How to use with clause on first of CYPHER statement on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

Unable to use with clause on beginning of CYPHER statement.

I want to set some parameter variable on with clause.
But, AgensGraph returns error.

```
agens=# with 1 as value return value;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: with 1 as value return value;
             ^
```

How to use with clause on beginning of statement?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Grammar has WITH clause also.

AgensGraph parser assume WITH clause on beginning as SQL WITH clause.

For avoid it, You can use dummy OPTIONAL MATH clause.

```
agens=# optional match (n) with 1 as value limit 1 return value;
 value 
-------
 1
(1 row)
```